# How to copy selected item in list box in C#?

Tags: c#, list, copy, clipboard

How to copy selected item in list box to clipboard, using right click "Copy" menu?

Comment: sharepoint ? SQL ? excel?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to select an item, and do ctrl + c then use this code:

```
 private void listBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control == true && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            string s = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 because of the completeness of the answer, but I would add that you need to check for a null selection otherwise it will throw an error if nothing is selected ( && listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0).

Answer (score 7):

To copy all the items in the listbox to the clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetText( string.Join( Environment.NewLine, ListBox1.Items.OfType<string>() ) );
```

To copy just the selected lines in the listBox to the clipboard (listbox SelectionMode is MultiExtended):

```
Clipboard.SetText( string.Join( Environment.NewLine, ListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<string>() ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

To manipulate text in the clipboard, you can use the static Clipboard class:

```
    Clipboard.SetText("some text");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I clicked on my listbox to create an automatic function inside the form class.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Clipboard.SetDataObject(this.listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

I added the Clipboard.SetDataObject() line and it works.